# FactoryGirl creating lists within lists - join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a join model I want to create ten instances of in testing. I want eight of those unique and two not.

The table is called job_locations, each instance having a job id and a location id. i want two of the ten jobs to use the same location id.

I am trying to do this with factory girl, but without having to laboriously write it all out by hand.

The closest I have come is this, which isnt very close at all i imagine, especially as I havent even begun to comprehend how I'll grab unique records.

```
job_locations = FactoryGirl.create_list(:job_location, 10, job: FactoryGirl.create_list(:job, 10), location: FactoryGirl.create_list(:location, 10))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's simplify building a `JobLocation` by using a trait which will populate its `job` association:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job_location do
    # Attributes here

    trait :with_job do
      job   { build(:job) }
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can call `FactoryGirl.build(:job_location, :with_job)` and it will return a `JobLocation` with a `Job` already built for you. This isn't required, but it saves you from writing `FactoryGirl.build(:job_location, job: FactoryGirl.build(:job))`, which is a lot less readable.

You can build (or create if you need persisted records) your objects with this piece of code:

```
locations     = FactoryGirl.build_list(:location, 8) + 
  FactoryGirl.build_list(:location, 1)*2

job_locations = locations.map do |location|
  FactoryGirl.build(:job_location, :with_job, location: location)
end
```

First, an array of `Location` objects is constructed. It's building 8 unique ones and then concatenates an array of 2 identical objects, after which you can build the array of `JobLocation` objects very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the readme and specs for create_list I don't think it takes arrays as default values, unfortunately. Unless that feature is untested and undocumented of course, in which case steer well clear...

Something like this would be far more verbose but declarative.

```
jobs = FactoryGirl.create_list(:job, 10)
locations = []; job_locations = []
jobs.each do |job|
  locations << location = FactoryGirl.create_list(:location, 10)
  job_locations << FactoryGirl.create(:job_location, 10, job: job, location: location)
end
```

And would allow individual items to be indexed easily.

Or write your own create_list helper, along the lines of:

```
def factory_create_list(name, count, params)
  list_params = params.delete(:list_params)
  (0..count-1).each_with_object([]) do |i, arr|
    build_params = params.merge(list_params.map { |p| p[i] })
    arr << FactoryGirl.create(name, build_params)
  end
end

factory_create_list(:thing, 20, user: user1, list_params: { location: [...], another_thing: [...] })
```

(Untested.)

But consider building or stubbing instead of creating where possible, for speed. (Less database access.) Also, your solution was a very long, impenetrable line. Split it up by assigning things to variables then assembling them in the last line, for clarity. You will thank yourself in 2 months.